# create an EC2 using Chef / knife socket error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, knife, ec2-ami

I am trying to create an EC2 using knife and knife-ec2 gem

command example :

```
knife ec2 server create --image ami-f7f03d80 -i --flavor t2.micro -x root -i /root/europe.pem —sud —groups chef-client -Z eu-west-1a -r “role[xmpp]”
```

Error output :

```
ERROR: Excon::Errors::SocketError: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known (SocketError)
```

knife.rb :

```
log_level                :info
log_location             STDOUT
node_name                'ec2-user'
client_key               '/root/.chef/ec2-user.pem'
validation_client_name   'chef-validator'
validation_key           '/etc/chef-server/chef-validator.pem'
chef_server_url          'https://ip-****.eu-west-1.compute.internal:443'
syntax_check_cache_path  '/root/.chef/syntax_check_cache'
knife[:aws_access_key_id]     = '*****'
knife[:aws_secret_access_key] = '*****'
knife[:region]                = 'eu-west-1a'
```

--

```
gem list knife-ec2
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
knife-ec2 (0.8.0)
```

Can any one put me on the right direction, i a m suspecting an issue with the ruby gems.

PS : 
for some reason knife ec2 flavor list works fine.

Thanks in advance.
regards,
Amine

> > > > > > > > > > > > >

SOLUTION :

fixed by : - reinstalling the ruby gems - reusing the patched version of ec2 create .rb

Answer (score 0):

That error means it's not able to resolve the hostname I believe. I'd start there.

Comment: hostname for which machine : 
local machine ?
or new one

I don't really get your point there.

Comment: my point is that's what the error means. Make sure any hostnames you are using can actually be resolved. I don't think you need the :443 at the end of that url. Try that.

Comment: fixed  by :
- reinstalling the ruby gems
- reusing the patched version of ec2 create .rb